Unable to fetch phantom wallet adapter
i am using reown appkit and from their docs, i have tried to get phantom wallet adapter button but when i click on it, it doesn't get detected even i have extension, and it has 2 phantom wallet button, it should have 1 the main above one.
can anyone help me where i am getting wrong.
import { createAppKit } from '@reown/appkit/react'
import { SolanaAdapter } from '@reown/appkit-adapter-solana/react'
import { solana, mainnet } from '@reown/appkit/networks'
import { PhantomWalletAdapter  } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets'
import { EthersAdapter } from '@reown/appkit-adapter-ethers'

// 0. Create the Ethers adapter
const ethersAdapter = new EthersAdapter()
const phantomAdapter= new PhantomWalletAdapter()

// 0. Set up Solana Adapter
const solanaWeb3JsAdapter = new SolanaAdapter({
  wallets: [phantomAdapter]
})

// 1. Get projectId from https://cloud.reown.com
const projectId = '4f69a130bfe8'


createAppKit({
  adapters: [ethersAdapter, solanaWeb3JsAdapter],
  networks:[solana, mainnet],
  metadata,
  projectId,
  enableWalletConnect:false,
  debug:true,
  featuredWalletIds:['a797aa35c0fadbfc1a53e7f675162ed5226968b44a19ee3d24385c64d1d3c393','c57ca95b47569778a828d19178114f4db188b89b763c899ba0be274e97267d96','1ae92b26df02f0abca6304df07debccd18262fdf5fe82daa81593582dac9a369'],
  features: {
    socials:[],
    email:false,
    analytics: true // Optional - defaults to your Cloud configuration
  }
})



as you can see these images, it is showing 2 phantom wallet, the above one is getting fetch from the extension and the 2nd one is getting fetched from featuredWalletIds, and if I click the 2nd one it says unable to detect, even though I have extension.
please help
